# SageMath: saving picture of graph to a file

Tags: python, sage

Given a graph defined in SageMath:

```py
G = Graph({...})
```

one can call `G.show()` to open a preview.
But how can I save this picture to file instead?

I'm aware I can do this within the preview dialog,
but I can't see an option to do this from code.

Something like `.write('/tmp/file')`.

- https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plotting/sage/graphs/graph_plot.html

I can use `latex`, write the output to a file, and then compile it with LaTeX, but this seems a little round the corner:

- https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_latex.html#module-sage.graphs.graph_latex

Answer (score 3):

The result of a call to `graph.plot()` is a sage Graphics object, which is the fundamental object for manipulating and saving graphics. To save the plot, name the Graphics object and call one of its save methods.

For a complete minimum example:

```py
# In sage session or script
G = graphs.WheelGraph(15)
p = G.plot()
p.save_image("myimage.png")  # saves the graph to myimage.png
```

Comment: Yessss :) thanks. I tried plot. But wasn't assigning it to a variable, which triggers opening the preview